# Filling out page contents from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I was asked to create a static HTML page that would load all of its contents from a separate JSON file. The first thing that I thought of was to give ids to the elements that would contain text nodes and append corresponding text then:

```
<div class="foo" id="FOO"></div>

...
var FOO = "lorem";
$("#FOO).text(FOO);
```

I have never done that before and wonder if there are any caveats or hidden obstacles in this approach. I mean I don't see any other way to do that, but that's gonna be hell of a lot of IDs, so I am not sure if I've studies all the possible ways to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of the markup alongside the json you'll be importing?  But having said that, there isn't any issues with having lots of ids, other than potentially being a real pain to maintain.  But, you could dynamically create the markup as you parse through the JSON, it would be a lot more flexible and take less time/effort.

Comment: Usually this is done when you have structured data that maps to the layout of the web page. For instance, an HTML table that corresponds to an array in the JSON.

Comment: Really not enough known about general structure. The same sets of element ID's can be easily used on numerous urls. Also html can be included in json data. Overall question is really too broad

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. @Barmar, I like the idea about using arrays for corresponding elements. That would be easier than assigning individual IDs to all of the menu items, for example.